# Does putting all the formatting in the topmost block improve performance of pdf generation?

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I have an xslfo code to generate pdfs and I'm using Apache FOP to do that. In each block I'm mentioning the formatting objects such as font family and size.
Can I move it to the top fo:block without degrading the performance?

Current Source:

```
<fo:block widows="2" orphans="2" font-size="10pt" line-height="1.147" white-space-collapse="false">
                    <fo:block space-after="8pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.2378041666666666" font-family="TimesNewRoman" font-size="11pt" text-align="center">
                        <fo:inline font-family="TimesNewRoman" font-weight="bold" font-size="14pt">
                            <fo:leader leader-length="0pt" />Some Title
                        </fo:inline>
                    </fo:block>

    <fo:block space-after="8pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.2378041666666666" font-family="TimesNewRoman" font-size="11pt" text-align="center">
                            <fo:inline font-family="TimesNewRoman" font-weight="bold" font-size="14pt">
                                <fo:leader leader-length="0pt" />Some Other Title
                            </fo:inline>
                        </fo:block>
    </fo:block>
```

Want to change to:

```
<fo:block widows="2" orphans="2" line-height="1.147" white-space-collapse="false" font-family="TimesNewRoman" font-size="11pt">

                        <fo:block space-after="8pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.2378041666666666" text-align="center">
                            <fo:inline font-family="TimesNewRoman" font-weight="bold" font-size="14pt">
                                <fo:leader leader-length="0pt" />Some Title
                            </fo:inline>
                        </fo:block>

        <fo:block space-after="8pt" space-after.conditionality="retain" line-height="1.2378041666666666" text-align="center">
                                <fo:inline font-family="TimesNewRoman" font-weight="bold" font-size="14pt">
                                    <fo:leader leader-length="0pt" />Some Other Title
                                </fo:inline>
                            </fo:block>
        </fo:block>
```

Sorry for the bad formatting of the code.
I need to give preference to the speed of generation of the document. Which would be better of the two?

Comment: That might depend completely on your xsl-fo processor and the PDF viewer in question.

Comment: line-height="1.2378041666666666" specifies the height to an accuracy of just about one atom. When you print at 1200 dpi, there's no sense in specifying measurements more accurate than 1/1200" or 0.02 mm. I suspect you're getting quite a speed hit here.

Comment: I'm using Apache FOP as the processor

Comment: *"Which would be better of the two?"* Why don't you just test it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

As someone who knows of the internals of (one) of the engines, the answer is a "very, very small" yes. Most engines are creating an internal tree of the formatting results that resolves all the inheritance. In this representation, all of what you have specified either as inherited or totally on each and every element is gone.

Now, that said. In the process of creating this, nodes are created and compared and the XML+XSL to XSL FO transformation takes memory and space for all of those nodes.

So, for example, specifying font-family (as the same font-family) on each and every element will likely be resolved internally in the engine to one font switch in the intermediate format of the engine, but of course it takes time and memory to analyze that and do it.

How much?

Minimal. There is much more time spent in deciding kern of letters, bidi direction, what fits on a line, what to do at page end, what to keep together and much, much more.

My guesstimate. 0.5%. The impact would be more from reading XSL FO files that are larger or creating them in memory if you are using XML+XSL. More memory is all. It can impact performance but very small.

Put tables inside of tables inside of tables and use keeps and continued headers = 20+%. Or choose a huge font like Arial Unicode and ask to one character from it like a single bullet.